# icon font: use bigger font-size (inline-element) without affecting line-height

Tags: html, css, fonts

i use an icon-font like…

```
<p> Bla bla bla <i data-icon="a"></i>
<br/> Second Line Bla bla bla bla bla </p>
```

because i need a bigger font-size for the icon i use css to do so…

```
p i{
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: -3px; /* to adjust the position */
}
```

but now the gap to the second line respectively the line height is bigger. i want that the i-inline-element is not influencing the line-height. 
i hope it is clear what i want to achieve. how can i do it?

i tried to add to the css

```
line-height: 0px
```

or something like this. but it does not work…

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/THnNe/1

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/P4JFg/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/P4JFg/2/ try with vertical-align: middle; -http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/

Answer (score 2):

line-height does work but if you have an icon in the first line the font size of the icon overreaches the line-height of the first line of your paragraph. So you can either try to not put icons in the first line or even out the overreach with negative margins.

```
i{
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0px;
}
p{
  margin-top:-10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e34QM/

Answer (score 1):

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/THnNe/4/)

**CSS**

```
.icon-video-1:before {
    font-size: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```